# Is there a cryptographic algorithm which is immune to side channel attacks?

Tags: cryptographic-hardware, side-channel-attack

Is there any cryptographic algorithm immune to side channel attacks based on scan chain? In VLSI point of view.

Answer (score 10):

A cryptographical algorithm can't be immune or not immune to side channel attacks; this is because a side channel attack attacks the implementation and not the actual algorithm.  Any algorithm that uses secret data can be implemented in a way that has side channel attacks, and any algorithm can be implemented in a way that may be resistant (the hard-core side channel attack guys will say that no implementation is totally immune) to side channel attacks.

That said, there are certainly algorithms that are easier to implement in a way that resists side channel attacks.

Comment: Some examples for the OP maybe?

Comment: Look at curve25519, it was thought in a way that counters side-channel attack by design. So that implementers can't hang themselves too much.

Comment: @David天宇Wong: can you point out what is in the design of curve25519 that counters scan chain based side channel attacks?  Or, for that matter, DPA or EMF side channel attacks?

Comment: _some_ side-channel attack! Sorry :) I know that the way it does point addition and doubling use the same amount of operations, and thus counters at least timing-attacks. Haven't read further

Answer (score 6):

Often people build hardware that contains cryptographic algorithms, and they are worried about what happens if that hardware falls into the hands of an attacker.

Historically, there have been several approaches to making it harder for the attacker, often used in some combination:

- Hardware and cryptographic algorithms specifically chosen or designed to comply with Kerckhoffs's principle: "A cryptosystem should be secure even if everything about the system, except the key, is public knowledge."
  Then switch to a new, fresh key whenever an old key may have fallen into the hands of an attacker. (Perhaps also use [zeroisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeroisation) to make it less likely that an old key will fall into the hands of an attacker).
- cryptographic algorithms specifically chosen or designed or re-implemented to be isochronous -- i.e., with data-independent runtime -- making them completely immune to timing attacks. (A good assembly-language programmer writing for a typical smartcard, which has no cache, can do this fairly easily. A FPGA designer can do this fairly easily. People writing code for processors that have a cache find that writing isochronous code is much more difficult, but often possible). (Unfortunately, this often makes such hardware slightly easier to attack with a differential power analysis side-channel attack).

  *
  Braun, Jana, Boneh.
  Robust and Efficient Elimination of Cache and Timing Side Channels".
  arXiv:1506.00189
  discussion: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9679762

  *
  Torbjorn Granlund.
  "Defeating modexp side-channel attacks with data-independent execution traces".
  https://gmplib.org/~tege/modexp-silent.pdf
- A white-box algorithm is completely immune to side-channel attacks. [white-box cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/white-box_cryptography)
  [white-box](/questions/tagged/white-box)
  http://www.whiteboxcrypto.com/ . White-box cryptographic algorithms are designed such that, even if the attacker knows *everything* about the system, including the keys for the hardware he has in his hand, he still cannot break the rest of the system.
  This was widely believed to be impossible,
  until ephemeral encryption keys, public key encryption, and public key signature authentication was developed.
  There have been some promising breakthroughs in [homomorphic-encryption](/questions/tagged/homomorphic-encryption) and [host-proof](/questions/tagged/host-proof) algorithms that seem to show that algorithms with useful white-box cryptographic properties are possible,
  and a few have already been useful in practice:
  (Public-key authentication using some certificate authority's public key happens every time a web browser accesses a "https://" website).
  (Ephemeral encryption happens every time a laptop or smartphone communicates with a recent WiFi access point).
  Unfortunately, we do not yet have a practical white-box algorithm for lots of other things we would like to do.
- various techniques such as shuffling, dummy operations, etc. to make timing and power side-channel attacks more expensive and less likely to succeed

  *
  Stottinger, Malipatlolla, Tian.
  "Survey of Methods to Improve Side-Channel Resistance on Partial Reconfigurable Platforms."
  doi: 10.1007/978-3-642-16767-6_4
- tamper resistance to make probing attacks more expensive and less likely to succeed.

Comment: When you say "isochronous -- i.e., with data-independent runtime", do you mean variable/random time but not based on secret data, or do you mean constant time (i.e. exactly the same number of time units)?

Comment: @Joost: I was thinking about the many systems that, every time some sensitive inner cryptographic function is used, that function always runs for exactly the same number of clock cycles. I thought the link in this answer would make it clear that such isochronous functions completely defeat timing attacks, in a ways that "add some random delay" is still vulnerable.

Comment: Right. There's another class of functions, though; those that are not vulnerable to timing attacks, but still take a varying amount of time (e.g. due to some rejection sampling from a PRG). My comment stems from the fact that there does not seem to be a clear word to describe such functions.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned side-channel attacks are an issue of algorithm implementation.

djb [implemented](https://nacl.cr.yp.to/index.html) a full suit of cryptographic primitives specifically with side-channel resistance in mind.

The idea is to prevent infromation flow from your secrets (private keys, messages, etc.) to those pieces of hardware which can be easily attacked, like CPU branch predictors, caches, TLBs, etc. [You can read in detail here](https://nacl.cr.yp.to/features.html).

Comment: The question specifically asked about scan-chain based side channel attacks; are you saying that djb's implementation protects against those attacks?

Comment: While it is an implementation issue at heart, it is true that an algorithm can be designed such that implementations free of side-channel attacks are more practical and performant.